# Diffeomorphism between $X$ of genus $g>1$ and the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: riemann-surfaces

> Is it automatic that a compact Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g>1$ is not homeomorphic to a compact subset of the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1?$

Note: I apologize for the confusion-I am just a high school student with an interest in math. This question was an offspring of my earlier question. Since it seemed sufficiently distant in nature, I decided to ask a new question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first examples of compact Riemann surface are $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ the Riemann **sphere** (genus $0$) and  $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z})$ a **torus** (a donuts, genus $1$). A compact Riemann surface of genus $n$ is in some sense  $n$ tori [glued together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)).

Comment: See the Weierstrass [function $\wp$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) which is the example of a meromorphic function $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{C}$ (an analytic function $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau\mathbb{Z})\to \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$)

Comment: One last question, when you say that a compact Riemann surface of genus $n$ ($X_n$) is (in some sense) $n$ tori glued together, does this mean the disjoint union of $n$ tori $X_n=\coprod_n(S^1\otimes S^1),$ or something else?@reuns

Comment: Or more precisely $\coprod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau_i\mathbb{Z})$ @reuns

Comment: Does [it look like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) a direct product of two complex tori ? Did you construct the complex torus $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z})$ yet ?

Comment: No, but maybe possibly under a deformation? Yes, I did. @reuns

Comment: A complex torus is the quotient of $\mathbb{C}$ by a lattice $\Lambda = \omega_1\mathbb{Z}+\omega_2\mathbb{Z}$ (whose elements act on $\mathbb{C}$ by translation). The direct product of two complex tori is $\mathbb{C}^2/(\Lambda \times \Lambda')$ the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^2$ by a lattice $\Lambda \times \Lambda'$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Locally it looks like an open of $\mathbb{C}^2$, it is **not** a (Riemann) surface.

Comment: Is there a standard construction of $X$ (of genus $g\ge 1$) from complex tori (I am using Forster's Lectures and I have yet to see this construction)? Thanks. @reuns

Comment: No. You need to stay in the genus $1$ setting and look at the [complex elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers) $y^2 = 4 x^3-ax-b$ before looking at $g \ge 2$ and quotients $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ of the upper half-plane by congruence subgroups. Of course, before all this you need to know a lot of complex analysis (theory of holomorphic functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The genus is a topological invariant, in particular a surface of genus $g \geq 1$ can't be homeomorphic to the Riemann sphere. Moreover, any subset of the Riemann sphere has boundary unlike a surface of genus $g$ so such an homeomorphism is also not possible.

On the other hand, any surface $S$ of genus $g \geq 2$ can be obtained as a quotient of the unit disk $D \subset \Bbb C$. A surface of genus 1 is more or less by definition $\Bbb C/ \Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. In view of this, can a compact subset of $X$ (with $g\ge 2$) be homeomorphic to a compact subset of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ where the compact subsets (of $X$) cover $X?$ @N.H.

Comment: Sure, you can cover $X$ by closed disks which are subset of $\Bbb CP^1$ but it not so interesting. On the other hand, something in this direction would be a branched covering : it's a map $f : X \to \Bbb P^1$ which is a local diffeomorphism except at finitely many points. This is a very interesting class of map.

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus Why don't you work [on $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_torus) instead of asking about things you can't even define (compact Riemann surfaces) ?

Comment: Do you think you can provide me with a reference to this map (perhaps Forster's lectures)? Also, is there a way to show that $\infty$ is one of these (finitely many) points? @N.H.

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite sure what you mean-compact Riemann surfaces are defined in most introductory texts on complex geometry. @reuns

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus Obviously you don't understand this definition..

Comment: This question was solely asked to help me make sure that I understood this object. As I said, I am still a novice in the subject area. @reuns

Comment: I think you should get a little more background in math before trying to understand Riemann surfaces, especially if you are a high-school student. Do you have a good understanding of complex analysis or topology ?
I would advice you to read the book "Introduction to topological manifolds" by Lee which contains all the prerequisites in topology for studying Riemann surfaces. It is an excellent book.

Comment: Thanks, I have just begun an "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by Lee. And yes, I have taken complex analysis (and have only been introduced to elementary topology via analysis) @N.H.